# AWSで請求を停止する方法

Tags: aws

AWSを無料枠で利用するつもりですが、毎月請求が発生してしまいます。

今月分（7月分）発生しているものは「Elastic Compute Cloud」の「Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud running Linux/UNIX」の「0.0116 per On Demand Linux t2.micro Instance Hour」です。

先月（6月分）はこのような請求は発生しておらず、また、7月にAWSに触った記憶はほとんどありません。
（何か原因だとしたら、先月分も75円ほど請求が発生しており、確かその請求を停止するために設定をいじる操作をして逆に今月分の請求が発生した…という可能性だと思われます。）

「実行中のインスタンス」も「Elastic IP」も削除した状態で、またリージョンの間違いもない状態で今月の請求が発生しているのですが、どうすればこの「0.0116 per On Demand Linux t2.micro Instance Hour」に関する請求を完全に停止できるでしょうか?

Comment: インスタンスが他のリージョン（日本以外）で動いていないでしょうか？また、インスタンスは削除されていますか

Answer (score 0):

私も同じことがありました。触る記憶がなかったが、請求が発生した。
もしかして、EBSのご利用料金でしょうか。

私の場合、請求を停止させるため、アカウントを削除した。